# Mobile navbar not spanning 100% width of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

My navbar on my Shopify site (Desktop) works fine but the mobile doesn't span 100% of the screen. It still works correctly but is there a way to make it span 100% of the viewport?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

`CSS`

```
/*================ Mobile Site Nav ================*/
.mobile-nav {
  display: block;
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.29, 0.63, 0.44, 1); }
  .sub-nav--is-open .mobile-nav {
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0); }
  .third-nav--is-open .mobile-nav {
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-200%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-200%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-200%, 0, 0); }

.mobile-nav__link,
.mobile-nav__sublist-link {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-size: 16px; }

.mobile-nav__link {
  position: relative; }

.mobile-nav__label {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; }
  .mobile-nav__link--active .mobile-nav__label {
    border-bottom-color: var(--color-text); }

.mobile-nav__sublist-link:not(.mobile-nav__sublist-header) {
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 30px; }

.mobile-nav__item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%; }
  .mobile-nav__item .icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    margin: -6px 0 0 -7px; }

.mobile-nav__return {
  border-right: 1px solid var(--color-border); }

.mobile-nav__return-btn {
  position: relative;
  padding: 24px 0;
  width: 55px; }

.mobile-nav__icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 22px;
  padding-right: 22px;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden; }

.mobile-nav__table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%; }

.mobile-nav__table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1%;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: normal; }

.mobile-nav__toggle-button {
  padding: 20px 15px; }

.mobile-nav__dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--color-body);
  z-index: 8;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  display: none; }
  .is-active + .mobile-nav__dropdown {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1; }
  .mobile-nav__dropdown.is-closing {
    transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.29, 0.63, 0.44, 1);
    opacity: 0.99; }
  .mobile-nav__dropdown .mobile-nav__sublist-header {
    font-family: var(--font-stack-header);
    font-style: var(--font-style-header);
    font-weight: var(--font-weight-header);
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 15px; }
  .mobile-nav__dropdown .mobile-nav__sublist-header--main-nav-parent {
    color: var(--color-body-text); }

*================ Mobile nav wrapper ================*/
.mobile-nav-wrapper {
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
/*   position: absolute; */
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: var(--color-body);
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.29, 0.63, 0.44, 1);
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%; 
  width: 100vw;
  }
  .mobile-nav-wrapper::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-border); }
  .mobile-nav-wrapper.js-menu--is-open {
    display: block; }

.mobile-nav--close .icon-hamburger {
  display: none; }

.site-header__mobile-nav {
  z-index: 11;
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--color-body); }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
    .site-header__mobile-nav {
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      width: 100% !important;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      -moz-align-items: center;
      -ms-align-items: center;
      -o-align-items: center;
      align-items: center; } }
```

`Full Rendered HTML`

https://pastebin.com/SAz1VczY

*Apologies for not including in the question; this exceeds the wordcount allowed.*

[image: Mobile Navbar]

Comment: try `width: 100vw` on the navbar as 100% follows the dimensions of closest parent that has a position property.

Comment: Thanks @zergski - I applied `width: 100vw` to `.mobile-nav` but it unfortunately still has the same outcome.

Comment: Is there anything else you would reccommend?

Comment: I don't see that you have a `position` property applied to the nav.. which mean that all its children are still taking 100% of the parent/grandparend that does.. try simply writing `position: relative` on the navbar

Comment: otherwise, is there a possibility of a demo of your site that I can inspect? I know the sensitivity about sharing work but it's the easiest way to determine the cause of the problem

Comment: and I see that the real parent for the navbar is the wrapper ( `<nav class="mobile-nav-wrapper medium-up--hide critical-hidden" role="navigation">` ), try applying the width and position property to it instead of the `<ul id="MobileNav" class="mobile-nav">` element

Comment: Applying `width: 100vw` and `position relative' to 'mobile-nav-wrapper` has fixed my issue when the navbar is open after clicking the burger icon but not when it's closed. I've updated the question with the updated CSS. We're getting close!

Comment: I've fixed it! I applied `width: 100vw;` to `site-header`. Thank you @zergski for all your help

Comment: Nice work my friend! Happy to help.